# Undefined step definitions in Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, python-behave

When I press Alt+Enter, I see Inspection 'Undefined Step' options. However, I should see the intention action Create Step Definition.

I have the Gherkin plugin installed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/02IUf.png

I cannot test because i get the info in my cmd:

```
ConfigError: No steps directory in 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\features'
```

Thanks in advance... i cant find answer to my problem online.

```
Feature: sign in to a pre-signed form  As a user I want to login and what happens

Scenario: Log in with valid data
    Given user is on Sign In form website
    When user sees filled in Sign In form and submits it
    Then User can see what's after being logged
```

Comment: Do you have professional version of pycharm? If the answer is no, then it's expected as mentioned  "This feature is only supported in the Professional edition. This edition is commercial, and it provides an outstanding set of features: see the comparison matrix for more details." in  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-step-definition.html page.

Comment: Check if the plugin Cucumber for Python is installed. This plugin enables Cucumber support with step definitions.