# "Undefined step reference" for existing steps in PyCharm Community with Gherkin plugin

Tags: pycharm, cucumber, gherkin, python-behave

## Problem

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.5 together with this [Gherkin plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9164-gherkin) (version 192.7142.26).

Even though the steps are found when running behave itself from the command line, the inspection in the editor always marks my feature files with "undefined steps reference".

## Example

My minimal working example uses the following folder structure:

```
└───features
    │   demo.feature
    │
    └───steps
            steps.py
```

With the following contents:

demo.feature:

```
Feature: Trying out Behave

  Scenario: Test
    When I do something
```

steps.py:

```
from behave import when

@when("I do something")
def do_something(context):
    print("It's something!")
```

Note that I have not applied any other settings, like marking any of the folders as sources root for example.
The quick fixes suggested by PyCharm do not provide me with a "Create step definition" option as well.

## Note

I know that PyCharm Professional supports BDD out of the box.
However, I would have thought that the Community Edition together with the plugin would also do the job.
Syntax highlighting etc. does work correctly, it only seems to be unable to find the step definitions.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this feature is only available in the Professional version of PyCharm. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-step-definition.html

Answer borrowed from here: [Undefined step definitions in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397898/undefined-step-definitions-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 2):

It can only resolved when you install the professional version of PyChram.

I searched many ways but no one worked.